# Reduce the size of an index format : text

Tags: java, file, text, indexing, information-retrieval

hello i have an inverted index format text in this format this:

term  document1 , document2  poids1 poids2

i want to reduce his size i haave reduce the name of the document for example
document 1 will became 1 .. also for the weight for example a weight of 2.5565465454 will be 2.55 like this for examle in java

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(w);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

please if u have any ideas u can suggests to me to reduce the size i don't need the code but just some ideas

Comment: Why would you want to reduce size of the text version? For text, pass it through a standard compression utility such as gzip... Otherwise if you want to reduce the size of the non-text inverted file structure itself, use index prunning... where you can remove entries from the postings list with too low weights...

Comment: thank u but the idea it to keep the rare words so i don't know if it the index prunning will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you have given is on a text file, which can be obtained from the text dump of an existing index (remember that an index is essentially organized as a binary, i.e. non-text file).

In that respect, there's not much of an use to trim a long document name, e.g. "Document-1" to "D1", because in typical implementations, e.g. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), documents and terms are identified by integer ids and not by their names.

Also, there's no point in trimming the trailing decimals, e.g. "0.25555" to "0.25" because they would take the same amount of storage space (typically 64 bits).

What may actually help you is the trimming utility of Apache Lucene, which is documented [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-pruning/org/apache/lucene/index/pruning/package-summary.html). This package supports index trimming by various different heuristic algorithms, the simplest of which is the tf and tf-idf based pruning, removal of an entry **(t, d)** from the posting list of term **t** that falls below a cut-off **tf (t,d)** or **tf (t, d) x idf(t)** value.